# Buck converter alternative 12V --> 3V

Tags: 12v, step-down

I'm looking to reduce  a battery supply voltage into a LILYGO T-Call and don't have a buck converter but do have lots of resistors and a few other components at hand.

I'm ideally looking for the optimal solution that is cleaner than chaining resistors together or using a large ohm resistor.

Comment: Define "optimal" because, as I read your question, using dropper resistors is sub-optimal.

Comment: The "optimal" solution (efficiency wise) is a buck converter.  The "optimal" solution interference and regulation wise is a linear regulator.  "A lot of resistors and other components" is in no way optimal.  A voltage divider or a series resistor are just right out.

Comment: Given that the T-Call has a GSM-module, you'll really want a buck converter with a large capacitor near the LILYGO power input.

Comment: If those few other components happen to include an LM317 and you're not too fussed about efficiency (which can't get any worse than resistors) consider a linear regulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no alternative here to a voltage regulator. It doesn't have to be a buck regulator, could be linear, too, but 9 V of voltage drop really suggests you don't want to do that: you'd be converting 3 times as much power as your 3 V circuit uses to heat. I don't know what a "lilygo t-call" is, but I'm assuming it draws more than a couple mA.

So, get a buck regulator IC. They're [surprisingly cheap](https://de.farnell.com/w/c/semiconductors-ics/power-management-ics-pmic/voltage-regulators/dc-dc-fixed-switching-regulators/prl/results?input-voltage-max=10v%7C11v%7C11.5v%7C12v%7C12.6v%7C14v%7C15v%7C16v%7C16.5v%7C17v%7C20v%7C22v%7C24v%7C28v%7C30v%7C34v%7C35v%7C36v%7C37v%7C38v%7C40v%7C42v%7C45v%7C60v%7C65v%7C75v%7C76v&range=inc-in-stock%7Cexc-delivery-surcharge&sort=P_PRICE) and you typically need 1 to 4 external components to make them work.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I was limited on time and the buck converters I had ordered hadn't arrived on time however later that day they came and so I was able to finish my project.